# Why does this webhook work in RStudio, but not command line?

Tags: r, cmd, webhooks, slack

I've built a simple script which uploads the contents of a .txt onto a Slack channel at regular intervals.

When I run it in RStudio it works fine, but when I run it from command line via a batch file it doesn't work. The code runs, prints expected outputs and doesn't crash, but nothing appears in the selected Slack channel. What's going on?

**logger.r**:

```r
    #required packages:    
    require(httr)
    require(tidyverse)
    library(jsonlite)

    options(stringsAsFactors = F)

    #System directories:
    winLogRoot = "C:/Users/Dave/source/repos/window logger/Release"
    current = paste0(winLogRoot,"/example.txt")

    #httr stuff:
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/[webhook url here]"



    waitTime = 60 # how often to check the text file
    while(1)
    {
      #Get first row of table
      winName = read.table(file = current, sep = "\n")
      sessHist = tibble(ts = as.character(Sys.time()),winName = paste0(winName$V1,"\n"))

      for(waits in 1:(300/waitTime)) # Send to slack every five minutes
      {
        print(waits) #debug string
        Sys.sleep(waitTime)
        winName = read.table(file = current, sep = "\n")
        ## Add another row to the tibble
        sessHist = rbind(sessHist,tibble(ts = as.character(Sys.time()), winName = paste0(winName$V1,"\n")))
      }
      #Turn the tibble into a string and post it to Slack
      print("attemping upload") #debug string
      body = toString(sessHist%>%as.matrix %>% t) 
      body = paste0('{"text":"',body,'"}')
      print(body) #debug string

#This is the bit that only seems to work when I run in RStudio
      httr::POST(url = url,body=body,encode = 'json')
    }
```

**logger.bat**:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" logger.R
```

**Command line ouptut**:

```
C:\Users\Dave\Documents\logger\win logger Rpart>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" logger.R
Loading required package: httr
Loading required package: tidyverse
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
v ggplot2 3.1.0       v purrr   0.3.1
v tibble  2.0.1       v dplyr   0.8.0.1
v tidyr   0.8.3       v stringr 1.4.0
v readr   1.3.1       v forcats 0.4.0
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

Attaching package: 'jsonlite'

The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':

    flatten

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] "attemping upload"
[1] "{\"text\":\"2019-05-12 15:26:46, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 15:32:55, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 15:39:05, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 15:45:16, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 15:51:26, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 15:57:36, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n\"}"
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] "attemping upload"
[1] "{\"text\":\"2019-05-12 15:57:37, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 16:03:47, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 16:09:57, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 16:16:07, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 16:22:17, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n, 2019-05-12 16:28:27, C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\n\"}"
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

So it's obviously running the Script, but not successfully using the webhook.

Bonus content: an existential crisis (the text file contains the name of the foreground window)

```
[1] 5
[1] "attemping upload"
[1] "{\"text\":\"2019-05-12 19:45:38, Why does this webhook work in RStudio, but not command line? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome\n, 2019-05-12 19:51:41, Why does this webhook work in RStudio, but not command line? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome\n, 2019-05-12 19:57:44, Why does this webhook work in RStudio, but not command line? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome\n, 2019-05-12 20:03:48, Why does this webhook work in RStudio, but not command line? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome\n\"}"
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

Comment: It's really unlikely that RStudio would be using the 32 bit version of R.  Maybe one of your libraries only works in 64 bits?

Comment: I agree, I think the 32-bit vs 64-bit is definitely a good first place to start. It might be helpful to print (or `cat` to a file) the `sessionInfo()` output just to see if there are any obvious inconsistencies (like architecture 32/64 bit issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I restarted my computer and now it's working. I guess this is the answer? But thanks for the advice about bits and whatnot. Glad that I don't have to work that out. :)